# I can't run my code using python language in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run hello world using python language but this error keep on prompting

[image]

> PS C:\Users`\OneDrive\Documents\pythonprog> python -u "c:\Users`\OneDrive\Documents\pythonprog\prog.py"
> C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\pythonprog\prog.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I've tried following videos on youtube but still having this error

Comment: In the error output you can see that `\`` character in the path is skipped. That might be the reason the file can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [ **`** ] in your folder path. Please modify your folder name, we suggest that the script path should be in ***full English* and does not contain *spaces* and *special symbols***.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try reloading VsCode and open your pythonprog folder in vs code . Then run your file.